# How to process my images to help Tesseract?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I have some images containing only digits, and a semicolon.

Example: [image: https://i.imgur.com/o4iz80V.png]

You can see more here: https://imgur.com/a/54dsl6h

They seem pretty clean and straightforward to me, but Tesseract considers them as empty "pages" (`Empty page!!`).

I tried both with oem 1 and oem 0 with a character list:

- `tesseract processed/35.0.png stdout -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789: --oem 0`
- `tesseract processed/35.0.png stdout`

What can I do to get Tesseract to recognize the characters better?

Comment: You can preprocess image using any image processing library before passing it to tesseract...Try playing with scale/sharpness/noise removal/dilation etc.. I think dilatio n should help here because the digits appear very thin to me..

Comment: Yes, these are already heavily processed, they come from game screenshots. I was basically asking which other transformations I could apply to help tesseract do its job. I'll try dilatation, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tesseract still gives me pretty bad results overall, but making the text bolder with a simple dilatation algorithm helped a bit.

In the end, since the font is really square, I used a trick, where I defined a bunch of segments for each digits, and depending on which segments intersect, or dont intersect with the digit, I can determine with 99% accuracy which digit it is.